# How can you reference the primary network interface of an EC2 instance in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, elastic-network-interface

In AWS-CDK I am trying to create a Traffic Mirroring Session. The EC2 machines are created in previous stacks and passed down as props to the new stack. However, while I am able to reference an ENI that was created explicitly (sniffing interface), I cannot find a way of referencing the EC2 primary network interface as the traffic mirror source

```
 class TrafficMirringStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope,id,props)

        const {
            suricataInstance,
            sniffingInterface,
            targetInstance
        } = props;


    const mirrorTarget = new ec2.CfnTrafficMirrorTarget(this, 'TrafficMirrorTarget', {
      description:' This is the traffic mirror target',
      networkInterfaceId: sniffingInterface.ref,
    });

    const mirrorFilter = new ec2.CfnTrafficMirrorFilter(this, 'TrafficMirrorFilter', {
      description: 'This filter allows all traffic from the target machine to be redirected to the sniffing interface',
      networkServices:[],
    });

    const allowAllInboundRule = new ec2.CfnTrafficMirrorFilterRule(this, 'InboundMirrorFilter', {
      destinationCidrBlock : '0.0.0.0/0',
      sourceCidrBlock:'0.0.0.0/0',
      trafficDirection: 'ingress',
      ruleAction: 'accept',
      ruleNumber:100,
      trafficMirrorFilterId: mirrorFilter.ref
    });

    const allowAllOutboundRule = new ec2.CfnTrafficMirrorFilterRule(this, 'OutboundMirrorFilter', {
      destinationCidrBlock : '0.0.0.0/0',
      sourceCidrBlock:'0.0.0.0/0',
      trafficDirection: 'egress',
      ruleAction: 'accept',
      ruleNumber:200,
      trafficMirrorFilterId: mirrorFilter.ref
    });

    
    const mirrorSession = new ec2.CfnTrafficMirrorSession(this, 'TrafficMirrorSession', {
      sessionNumber: 1,
      networkInterfaceId: targetInstance.instance.networkInterfaceId,
      trafficMirrorFilterId: mirrorFilter.ref,
      trafficMirrorTargetId: mirrorTarget.ref
    })
    }
}
```

and I get the following error

```
Error: TrafficMirroringStack/TrafficMirrorSession [AWS::EC2::TrafficMirrorSession] is missing required property: networkInterfaceId
```

Comment: have you attempted to use the SDK to retrieve the information? Many CDK Constructs do not actually have all the information attached to them because many of that information is only known at deployment time.  The CDK always assumes it is a first deployment, and will require you to find your own answers for many things - using the SDK is the accepted solution for many such cases.

Also, be warry of passing constructs as props to other stacks. Unless they are all NestedStacks contained in the same common stack, a change in one can lock deployments because they depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
instance.networkInterfaces
```

and find the interface you want.

see docs:
[networkInterfaces - aws cdk doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.CfnInstance.html#networkinterfaces-1)